# AJAX: $_GET returns no values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Been trying to figure this out for hours...

I am attempting to use AJAX by grabbing values from a jQuery slider I have contained in an `<input>` tag. AJAX does not fail (see code), and when I `console.log` the variable I am trying to send through `Data:`, it prints out correctly.

**note**: The jQuery and php are on the same page, so no `url:` parameter, or whatever you will call it is used.

Here is the `<script>` portion:

```
   jQuery(function($){
        $("input[id='protein-slider']").ready(function(){
            var p_range;
            var request;
            $("input[id='protein-slider']").each(function () {
            p_range = $(this).val();
            });
            console.log(p_range) //Returns correct values

            request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: p_range,
            });  
            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log("Hooray, it worked!"); //This prints, no error
            });
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.error(
                    "The following error occurred: "+
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );
            });
        });
    });
```

and the `<?php ?>` code in correlation with this function is:

```
                echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //returns nothing
                $income_data = $_GET['p_range']; 
                echo $income_data; //returns nothing
                var_dump($income_data); //returns "NULL"
```

I've lost track of all of the other methods I have done and the other countless awnsers I have read on here. None seem to work and it's getting quite depressing...

Hopefully one of you guys can spot something that I am doing stupid...

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `$_POST['p_range'])`

Comment: How have you verified that the PHP code doesn't return the desired result? You're not logging the response in your js code.

Comment: @Kris do you know how to log `data`?

Comment: @Kris I used: `error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message' + err); }` and nothing was printed to the console. As for checking if PHP has the desired result, wouldn't var_dump() show me something if it did give me the desired result?

Comment: But how are you looking at the PHP output? Do you use e.g. the Net tab of Firebug to see the response? What happens when you add `console.log(response);` to your done function?

Comment: @Kris I have never used the Net tab before, but nothing shows up related to what I am trying to do here. `console.log(response)` prints out what looks like the HMLT markup of the same page I am working on, and trying to send the data to.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what your testing strategy is. You visit the PHP page in your browser, correct? Then you change the slider, expecting an AJAX POST to happen to the PHP page. The PHP page somehow knows (how?) not to render the original contents, but instead processes the incoming data. The response is sent back to the browser and ends up in the `response` variable. However when you log this variable, you see some HTML contents. Something is thus wrong with your code which decides whether to render a page or process results... Can you post some more of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax is for POST, change it to GET

```
request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: p_range,
});
```

or you access your params in php as

```
$var = $_POST['p_range'];
```

Comment: what are you getting in response and in print_r($_POST);

Comment: Sorry just saw this not. `print_r($_POST);` gives me nothing, however `print_r($_REQUEST);` gives me `Array ()`

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs to be in key/value pair

```
data: {p_range: p_range},
```

and

```
$income_data = $_POST['p_range'];
```

Comment: Could it maybe be because I am calling the jQuery function after the variables are set in PHP? Therefore, when the variables are echoed they don't contain anything?